# Grep command in python

Tags: python, grep

I wanted to write this command in python

```
grep "event 212" */*/test.log
```

the number after event is given by variable `k`

My code is:

```
for k,v in pmu_dict.items():
        grepCMD= "grep"+" "+\""event"+k\"+" "+args.path+" "+"*/*/test.log"
```

Please help me correct the syntax.

Comment: Try `'grep "event {}" */*/test.log'.format(k)`

Comment: But actually, you shouldn't be building this command string at all. Use `subprocess` and pass the command and its arguments as a list.